# selector and PerformSelector

Tags: ios, uitableview, selector

I have a `UITableView` with several sections. Each section contains a different set of data: phoneNumbers, addresses....

For each of those sets I have a model: PhoneNumber, Address. They're completely different but have some methods in common.

In my `UITableView` I have an array containing those models/classnames:

NSMutableArray *classNames;

In the `viewDidLoad` of my `UITableView` I do some initializations for all those sections:

```
//section 1: PhoneNumbers
phoneNumbers = [PhoneNumbers getAllIDs];
if (phoneNumbers && (phoneNumbers.count >0)) {
    [classNames addObject:@"PhoneNumber"];
    [dataIDs addObject:phoneNumbers];
}
```

I do this again for all the other sections/models:

```
 //section 2: Addresses
    addresses = [Address getAllIDs];
    if (addresses && (addresses.count >0)) {
        [classNames addObject:@"Address"];
        [dataIDs addObject:addresses];
    }
    // section 3: .....
```

Ok so far for initialization. This looks good and works fine.

Then later on in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I'm retrieving the actual data via those ID's

```
NSInteger section = [indexPath section];                    
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

NSArray *rows = [dataIDs objectAtIndex:section];        
NSNumber *recordID = [rows objectAtIndex:row];
```

I then figure out in what class we have to fetch the actual data:

```
Class displayedDataClass = NSClassFromString ([classNames objectAtIndex:section]);
```

and get the data to populate the cell.

```
id displayedRecord = [[displayedDataClass alloc] init];      
[displayedRecord getByID:recordID];
```

I can then set the labels in my cell using :

```
[cell.someLabel setText:[displayRecord fullDesciption]];
```

So far so good, I succesfully abstracted everything, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`doesn't need to know where things come from, as long as those classes respond to the methods for retrieving the data for the labels (in the case above fullDesciption)

Now I need an actionButton in every Cell performing some kind of action
To make sure I understood the concept of selectors and performSelection I just quick and dirty made in action in my TableView Class:

```
- (void) buttonTarget {
    NSLog (@"yes");
}
```

And in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method created a button with the following target:

```
button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTarget) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Ok, so far so good, things work like expected. But this is not what I really wanted. The action should not be performed here, but in the actual class (PhoneNumber,Address,...).

To keep things clean I made a model Action, containing the icon for the button, a description and the selector:

```
@interface Action : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *icon;
@property (nonatomic ) SEL selector;

@end
```

In my PhoneNumber class (and similar classes) the action is set to the correct selector:

```
Action  *phoneAction = [[Action alloc] init];

phoneAction.description = NSLocalizedString(@"Call", @"Call button description");
phoneAction.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"phone"];
phoneAction.selector = @selector(callPhone);
```

Of course callPhone is implemented in the PhoneNumber class.

In my TableView I then get the actions for that cell

```
action = [displayedRecord action];
```

I then try to use that selector in my Button:

```
[button addTarget:displayedRecord action:[action selector] forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But here things go wrong: we never arrive in that method and I get the following error:

> [UIDeviceWhiteColor callPhone]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x874af90 2013-12-29 23:23:03.629 thinx[27242:907] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[UIDeviceWhiteColor callPhone]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x874af90'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a zombie. When you get an action being sent to an object that makes no sense, it usually means that your object is being deallocated before you can send a message to it.

In your case, you're adding "displayedRecord" as the target for your button.

In order for that to work, you need to keep a strong reference to displayedRecord call for the lifetime of your button object. What owns your displayedRecord object?

If you can't debug this from looking at your code you can use the zombies instrument to try to figure it out.

Comment: This is probably an answer in the right direction!! "displayedRecord" is defined in cellForRowAtIndexPath (as written in my question). But since it's a local variable, it's probable not 'strong' enough. How do I accomplish that ?

Comment: Is there only one displayedRecord object, or do you create one for each cell? If there's only one, make it a property of your view controller. If there is a different one for each cell, create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell with a property (of type id) to hold the displayedDataClass object for that cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot Duncan. This was really THE solution. I know have a nice implementation where the functionality is abstracted and put where it belongs! I already had a custom class for my UITableViewCell so adding that property was easy (at first it didn't work but I forgot to make the instance variable in my custom UITableViewCell strong!)

Answer (score 0):

In your unrecognized selector error you sent the message to an object called UIDeviceWhiteColor. Does that class have a method called callPhone? It seems to me that displayedRecord is not pointing to the object you think it is.

Comment: I don't have a class UIDeviceWhiteColor in my code. My PhoneNumber class does have an callPhone Class.

Comment: The stack trace is telling you that the object being called, UIDeviceWhiteColor - an Apple SDK private class, is receiving your message. Meaning, your variable displayedRecord is pointing to that for some reason. I would guess somewhere you are accidentally assigning it. Set some breakpoints and check its class type

Comment: As another gentleman pointed out you could have a zombie. It might be helpful to go into the Debug settings and Enable Zombies.